# Jquery upload file and read list of files from folder always return same count on IE

Tags: jquery

My J query code to upload file to a folder is working well. when I read the file names from the same folder first time it is retrieving correct values but on multiple uploads it is not retrieving the last updated files in response.

this issue is only on IE but my code works fine in chrome.

Please find my code below for reading the content from folder and suggest me if there is anything wrong.

```
$.ajax({
        url: responseText,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
               $(data).find("a").each(function () {
                $('#' + itemId).append($("<a target='_blank' href=" + responseText + "/" + filename + ">" + this.innerText + "</a> <br/>"));
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a `}` too many.

This is (one of the reasons) why proper [**indentation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) is so important!

---

#### Code after fixing indentation & removing `}` :

```
$.ajax({
    url : responseText,
    type : "GET",
    cache : false,
    success : function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").each(function () {
            $('#' + itemId).append($("<a target='_blank' href=" + responseText + "/" + filename + ">" + this.innerText + "</a> <br/>"));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I missed the extra } any how you fixed Mr.John. Good catch.. any suggestion on the issue?

Comment: @Chenna : Besides the `}`, I can't see anything wrong with the code you provided. If the issue persists, please show us some more relevant code. Or, even better, give us a link with a demo where we can do some debugging.